# subprocess or threading differences between Python 2.7 and 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-2.7, subprocess

I'm using the following code to execute a subprocess (a Python 3 script).  When run using Python 3, the code correctly reads the output of the subprocess.  When run using Python 2.7, I get no output.  This script is just a test script, I need to actually run the subprocess from a larger Python 2.7 application, so I can't just do it using Python3.

```
# client.py:  test client for communicating with the wrapper

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def read_it():
    print(u"read_it thread running")
    while True:
    
        for msg in process.stdout:
            print(u"subprocess output: {}".format(msg.rstrip()))
        

print(u"subprocess starting")
process = Popen(['/usr/bin/python3', './wrapper.py', 'arg1', 'arg2'], 
                                stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, close_fds=True, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
print(u"subprocess running: {}".format(process.pid))
                                
thread = Thread(target=read_it)
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()

sleep(5.0)  # wait for initial output from subprocess
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me using `2.7.16` and `3.8.2`.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer How did you test it without wrapper.py?

Comment: @Flyingdiver: I used: `import time; for x in range(10): print(x, time.time())`

Comment: Hmm.  I'm using sys.stdout.write, not print.  Let me try that.

Comment: Nope, still no output using Python 2, and broken pipe error in Python3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the file io buffering between the versions is the issue.  But this works for both Python versions:

```
# client.py:  test client for communicating with the wrapper

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def read_it():
    print(u"read_it thread running")
    while True:
    
        msg = process.stdout.readline()
        print(u"subprocess output: {}".format(msg.rstrip()))
        

print(u"subprocess starting")
process = Popen(['/usr/bin/python3', './wrapper.py', 'arg1', 'arg2'], 
                                stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, close_fds=True, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
print(u"subprocess running: {}".format(process.pid))
                                
thread = Thread(target=read_it)
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()

sleep(5.0)  # wait for initial output from subprocess
```